# Why any user can edit another user Public page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I created 3 users for testing(user test1, test2, test), but when i logged in by user test1 and access test2's public page, i can edit that page ???
how to config to disable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean with "edit the page":

- If all users have the "Administrator" role, they will be able to add portlets to the page
- It's a public page, so by default everybody can access that page. If there's a Wiki with public write permissions, everybody will be able to edit that Wiki.
- If the users are "friends" - either explicitly or implicitly through belonging to the same organization - they can write on each other's wall

As you state in the comments to this answer, just the PowerUser or the User role for a single user seem to be enough for your users: Try to reproduce this on a new installation - e.g. download the version you have (and the latest available) and see if you can reproduce there. It might be that the permissions for these roles are messed up. You can also compare what a User (role) is allowed to do in Control Panel / Roles / [Power]User / Define Permissions - compare your installation with a default install.

Also, you don't state what version you're using. I couldn't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: thank Olaf, user test1 can add portlet and edit content to test2's public page, all user just register normally :|

Comment: I have checked user role, all new user have Power user role, so can i configure to disable :)

Comment: out-of-the-box PowerUser is not able to edit other user's pages - only their own, right? Did you change it? Or did you refer to the content of those pages?

Comment: sorry, i do that, but when user have only User role(no Inherited Roles), that user still change other public page, can you explain me why :|

Comment: I use Liferay 6.1, User role have only Action View, but the problem still occur :|

Comment: User can add portlet, but can not remove portlet from page.

Comment: Now, user can not edit other public page, but user can do that to administrator public page :|